# Program Files folder instead of Program Files (x86) installation path in wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am making a Windows installer and I am using the following directory structure for the installation path:

```
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
   <Directory Id="Company" Name="CompanyName">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="ProductName" />
   </Directory>
</Directory>
```

The above code snippet will install my app in the "Program Files (x86)" folder. My application only runs on a 64 bit version of Windows so I would like to install it in the Program Files folder instead. How can I do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `ProgramFiles64Folder` instead of `ProgramFilesFolder`.

Besides that, set:

`Product/Package/@Platform="x64"`

`Product/Package/@InstallerVersion` to at least 200

`Component/@Win64="yes"`

For .NET assemblies:

`File/@ProcessorArchitecture="x64"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got the first line. Could you please tell me how to set the following lines? you mean like this? <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64"/>

Comment: @AminMerati Exactly!

Comment: @maxp Thanks for beautifying!

Comment: You can do this, but know that there's [an easier way](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/05/14/working-hard-or-hardly-working). Basically, pass the -arch parameter to candle.exe, or if you're using Votive, set the Platform dropdown in Visual Studio to x64.